# OUT or INOUT argument for routine ... is not a variable or NEW pseudo-variable in BEFORE trigger

Tags: c#, mysql

I have a mySQL stored procedure that I'm calling from C#.  I want to return an output parameter that gives me the AutoIncrement key back.

In my stored procedure I have this which should assign the key to the return parameter:

```
Select Last_Insert_ID() into p_Transaction_ID;
```

I call using ExecuteNonQuery from c#.  When the command executes I get the following error:

> OUT or INOUT argument for routine ... is not a variable or NEW
>   pseudo-variable in BEFORE trigger

Searched all morning, but can't figure out why it won't take and return the param.

I do have a work around using ExecuteScalar an just doing "Select Last_Insert_ID()" at the end of the stored procedure.  It's ugly, but works...

I would, however, like to get it working by using a return param.

Comment: Please post code from `trigger` body that calls the stored procedure.

Comment: Do you use [Connector/Net](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/index.html)? Check [6.9.1 Using Stored Routines from Connector/Net](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-programming-stored-using.html).

Comment: Yes.  I use Connector.Net.  Thanks for the link.  Sorry I have not been able to post more code details yet.